# Parse JPasswordField result

Tags: java, swing, jframe, comparison, jpasswordfield

I'm fairy new to Java so I don't even know if I'm doing this correctly but I have created a GUI with a text field, a password field and button. I have an event listener on the button. When it's pressed, the listener will check the name and password fields but it is currently not working as intended.

Event code:

```
public class event implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {
        String name = textfield.getText();
        char[] temp_pass = password.getPassword();
        String pass = new String(temp_pass);

        if (name == "Spedwards" && pass == "test") {
            result.setText("Welcome Liam");
        } else {
            result.setText("Unknown User");
        }
    }
}
```

The way I understand this, is it gets the text from the text field and the password field then checks to see if it equals `Spedwards` and `test` respectively, then sets the text for the label I have on the GUI. Currently however, it only sets the text as `Unknown User` regardless of putting in the correct information or not.

Why does it do this and how can I correctly get the values I need?

Comment: use str1.equals(str2) to compare Strings.

Comment: @XingFei I completely forgot Java had `.equals()` method. I'm used to Javascript where you just have `==`

Comment: There's a reason why the password field doesn't return a String, you shouldn't be making the char array into a String, this is a security hole

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm just learning at the moment. If I ever did release a product I certainly wouldn't be doing it this way.

Comment: The learn to do it properly, perfect practice makes perfect ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments.
The secure way to compare Strings is using String.equals() method

Change the line

`if (name == "Spedwards" && pass == "test") {`

to

`if ("Spedwards".equals(name) && "test".equals(pass)) {`